Liquidity.fetchAllPoolKeys returning TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toBase58')
I wanted to fetch all Liquidity pools on Raydium using the const { Liquidity } = require('@raydium-io/raydium-sdk'); with const pools = await Liquidity.fetchAllPoolKeys(this.connection, { '4': LIQUIDITY_PROGRAM_ID_V4 });
I always get an TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toBase58') The error seems to be coming from the '4': LIQUIDITY_PROGRAM_ID_V4 somehow not being able to be read but I sadly have no idea whatsoever whats wrong with it.
Would appreciate help :)
Thanks

The @raydium-io/raydium-sdk was archived and no changes have been made to it in over five months. Upon switching to v2 @raydium-io/raydium-sdk-v2 I couldn't find a method to fetch all pool keys
You might want to use the API directly.
API Swagger docs -> https://api-v3.raydium.io/docs/

Thank you, solved the problem for me. Using the v3 http api does the job, as well as the /pools/key/ids endpoint gets me the pool ids
